# Retrieve data from 3rd party website by ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have ajax in my `cart` page where i get destination info of the user and return shipping options to them in order to calculate their shipping cost.

So far everything works ***except I'm not sure how to loop returned data*** from my 3rd party website.

**Here is what I need:**

I need Loop trough this data and get marked information in drop-down.

> Red: as my option group.
>
> Orange - Green - Purple:  as my option. LIKE:
>
> `OKE - 48.000 - 5-7 Days`

`network result`

[image: screen1]

`console result`

[image: screen2]

## Codes

This is my ajax code for that:

```
<script>
  jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('body').on('change', 'select[name="city"]', function(e){
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });

       var cityID = $(this).val();
       var weight = ["{{$totalWeight}}"];
        if(cityID) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('rajaajax') }}/'+weight+'/'+encodeURI(cityID),
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {
                // $('#des').empty();
                // $('#des').append(
                //   '<p>Destination: ' + data['meta']['destination']['province'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['type'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['city_name'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['postal_code'] +'</p>'
                //   );
                $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
                  console.log(value);
                });
              }
            });
        }else{
          $('select[name="postchoose"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

I retrieved my data with code below:

```
    <script>
  jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $('body').on('change', 'select[name="city"]', function(e){
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });

       var cityID = $(this).val();
       var weight = ["{{$totalWeight}}"];
        if(cityID) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '{{ url('rajaajax') }}/'+weight+'/'+encodeURI(cityID),
              type: "GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(data) {
                $('#des').empty();
                $('#des').append(
                  '<p>Destination: ' + data['meta']['destination']['province'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['type'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['city_name'] + ' , ' + data['meta']['destination']['postal_code'] +'</p>'
                  );
                $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
                  $.each(value.costs, function(key2, value2) {
                    $.each(value2.cost, function(key3, value3) {

                      // number format
                      var number = value3['value'];
                      var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                          maximumFractionDigits:0, 
                          minimumFractionDigits:0
                      });
                      var formattedNumber = nf.format(number);
                      // number format
                      $('select[name="postchoose"]').append('<optgroup label="' + value['code'] + '" /><option id="postchoose" class="form-control" value="'+ value['code'] +'">'+ value2['service'] + ' - ' + nf.format(number) + ' Rp' + ' - ' + value3['etd'] +'</option></optgroup>');

                      // console.log(value);
                      // alert(value.code); // jne-pos
                      // alert(value2.service); //oke -reg
                      // alert(value3.value); // 43000 - etd 24 jam
                    });
                  });

                });
              }
            });
        }else{
          $('select[name="postchoose"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

there is only `1` issue i'm facing I would like to be done and that's grouping results with `<optgroup>` as you see in my screenshot below my `<optgroup>` in looping for each one of my options.

[image: screen3]

How can I fix this?